# How to append a String to the end of Text box python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tkinter, append

I am using python 3.7.5

How to append or insert a string at the end of textbox?
without deleting the previous text

I did this as I found in different tutorials

```
import tkinter
win=tkinter.Tk()
textF = tkinter.Text(win)
textF.pack()

textF.insert(END,'s')
```

but it did not work ,
and it shows me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    textF.insert(END,'s')
NameError: name 'END' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `tkinter.END` and not just `END`

Comment: could you tell me what constant refer to the beginning of text?

Comment: It's index based. So, use `0`

Comment: If I am using get and END constant it does not work : get(index1=0, index2=tkinter.END)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I am now trying to take the whole string, using get() method